# Using ant-design-vue Notification with a link in the message section

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, antd

I'm trying to add a link to the notification message but it's always being interpreted as a string

I'm using ant design for Vue

```
this.$notification.error({
        message: 'error please contact <href="mailto:test@test.com?subject=test">',
        duration: 15
      });
    });
```

I tried many things but nothing worked, I also tried that "message" beacome a funtion that returns a string with html but didn't work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [docs](https://antdv.com/components/notification/) said, the `message` type is `string|vueNode |function(h)`.

So you can use `vueNode` or `function(h)` to create `html string`.

The below is the [function (h)](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#createElement-Arguments) example.

```
     this.$notification.error({
        message: function(h) {
          return h("div", [
            "error please contact",
            h(
              "a",
              {
                attrs: {
                  href: "mailto:test@test.com?subject=test"
                }
              },
              ["link name"]
            )
          ]);
        },
        duration: 15
      });
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-butterfly-z1zf8?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Thank you :) , I also found the answer here https://ant-design-vue.github.io/antv-doc/components/notification/ (example custom icon). The example of custom icon in https://antdv.com/components/notification/ is wrong and it's for react

Comment: It runs perfect, you can also use the Vnode and it's easier. `message: <div>message <a href="/test">link</a></div>,
       `

Comment: I updated the code, you can visit the https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-butterfly-z1zf8?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work for me, I have always a Failed to compile error